# Get sum in promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm studying promises and would like to see the total time taken to execute a sequence of promises using the code below:

```
    function rand(min, max) {
    min *= 1000;
    max *= 1000;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}
var total = 0;

function criaPromises(valor, time) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            total = (Number(time) + Number(total))
            resolve(total)
        }, time)
    })
}

let promises = [
    criaPromises('Promise 1', rand(1, 10)),
    criaPromises('Promise 2', rand(3, 5)),
    criaPromises('Promise 3', rand(3, 7))
]

Promise.all(promises).then((total) => {
    console.log(`Todas as promises terminaram de executar e isso demorou um total de ${total} segundos!`)
})
```

But I've already inserted `total = (Number(time) + Number(total))` everywhere... But it only returns **NaN** or just the time of each promise separated by commas like `19276,3843,10364`.

Comment: This is an English site. Portuguese is [over there](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: `Promise.all` returns an array of the resolved promises in order, in this case an array of each of the times... you'll need to sum them up (check `Array.reduce` for a simple way to do so). Also, no need to cast numbers to numbers.

Comment: The three calls to `criaPromises()` will be made in parallel, therefore the three setTimeout timers will start at (very nearly) the same time. As the timeout times are random, it is not known in which order the promises will resolve. Any of the three could be the last to resolve. The value with which the *last* Promise resolves will be the sum of the three `time` values passed to `criaPromises()`, This value will be given by `${Math.max(...total)}` (It is confusing to reuse variable name `total` for the Array passed to the `.then()` callback).